# How can I tokenize two different strings with same stringstream object?

Tags: c++, tokenize

How can I tokenize two different strings with same `stringstream` object?

I was trying the following code but it doesn't work:

```
using namespace std;

void check()
{
        stringstream s( "This is a test");
        string token;

        while (s>>token)
        {
              cout<< token <<'\n';
        }
        s.str("hello world");
        while ( s>> token )
        {
              cout<< token <<'\n';
        }
}

int main()
{
    check();
    int z;
    cin>>z;
}
```

Comment: The eof bit is set when you reach the end of the stream with `>>` in the first while loop. That is why you need to call `clear()` to reset the stream as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

you need to reset the stream flags by doing [s.clear();](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/):

```
stringstream my_stringstream( "This is a test");
string token;

while ( my_stringstream >> token )
{
      cout<< token <<'\n';
}

my_stringstream.str("hello world");
my_stringstream.clear();

while ( my_stringstream >> token )
{
      cout<< token <<'\n';
}
```

The eof bit is set when you reach the end of the stream with `>>` in the first while loop. That is why you need to call clear() to reset the stream as shown in the answer.
Thanks Jesse Good for the addition.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
while (s >> token)
```

...does rather a lot. As well as getting a `token` from `s`, [operator>>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) returns the stream (`s`). `while` then evaluates this `s` by [converting it to either a `bool` (since C++11) or a `void*` (before C++11)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). This is *essentially* the same as `!`[`fail()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail). Now if `fail()` returns `true` and you have broken out of the first loop, you're not going to enter the second loop until `eofbit`, `badbit` and/or `failbit` have been reset. You reset these with [`clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear), as demonstrated below:

```
void check()
{
    stringstream s( "This is a test");
    string token;

    while (s >> token)
    {
        cout << token << '\n';
    }

    std::cerr << "Before s.clear(), s.fail() is " << std::boolalpha << s.fail() << std::endl;

    s.clear();

    std::cerr << "After s.clear(), s.fail() is " << std::boolalpha << s.fail() << std::endl;

    s.str("hello world");
    while (s >> token)
    {
        cout << token << '\n';
    }
}
```

[See it run](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1AHuUZ%240)!